# Swift - Getter and Setter for Computed Properties as String type

Tags: swift, getter-setter, computed-properties

Hello im really new to Swift development with no Objective-C background, although I have a strong fundamentals in java, swift has a very stiff learning curve for me, well I'll go straight to my question, but ill post the code first

```
 class Vehicle {

    var gear : String {

        get {
            return self.gear
        }

        set {
            self.gear = newValue
        }
    }
}

var vehicle = Vehicle()
vehicle.gear = "ADASD"
```

im having a compiler error saying

```
./run-swift: line 18: 30295 Segmentation fault: 11  gtimeout -k $TIMEOUT_KILL_AFTER $TIMEOUT_DURATION $SWIFT_COMPILER -target $TARGET -sdk $SDK $OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL $INPUT_FILE -o $OUTPUT_FILE
```

i realy dont understand as why this simple code does not compile using a String type, if I change the variable declaration as Int type and assign a value to its property i have no problems at all.

Answer (score 3):

`self.gear` here calls the getter for `gear` which calls `self.gear`. You've created an infinite loop. You have a similar situation for the setter. You don't need to implement `get` and `set` if you just want to store a property.

```
final class Vehicle {
    var gear : String
}

var vehicle = Vehicle()
vehicle.gear = "ADASD"
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but im testing something with property observers(willSet/didSet) in inheritance from the websites tutorial, and I dont understand  when I tried to change gear as an Int type and do this -> _vehicle.gear = 2
print(vehicle.gear);_ , I dont have problems at all, but the output is _140543825397248_ , I really dont understand the internal semantics of Swift's data types.

Comment: I can't reproduce this working correctly if you just change `String` to `Int`. That would be very surprising. It may not crash as quickly (or possibly at all), since Int doesn't requiring allocating memory, but it shouldn't really work. It's an infinite loop. The fact that you get a bizarre answer is likely due to you overflowing your stack (which I would expect) and getting a garbage result rather than crashing.

Comment: sorry I didnt post were I compiled the code, Im a windows user, i dont have mac here, so im just using their swift's online compiler which is here 
[link]http://www.runswiftlang.com/ , if you try to change the gear as an Int type and assign an int value, youll get those numbers and I dont understand why :(, but thanks for giving me a hint "It's an infinite loop", Swift has a very very very different semantics, and as a Java aspirant, this one is a bit hard. :(

Comment: You'll get those errors because when you overflow the stack (due to calling the setter in an infinite loop), the behavior is undefined. When you overflow the stack, anything can happen next. Remove the unnecessary `get` and `set`.

Comment: thanks, now i understand the semantics of property observers, I didnt realize that swift's _get_ and _set_ is NOT as simple as java's mutator and accessors, i didnt realize that a property call's it self if it is used inside its own observers. [Edit], _"When you overflow the stack"_ -> i hope swift can throw me a Stackoverlow -_-

Answer (score 1):

some addition to Rob's answer:

`computed property` is just the front door for some backing stored variables, in your case, the right way is declaring `stored variables` first, and using `computed property`'s `get set method` to access it

```
class Vehicle {
    private var _gear : String = ""
    var gear : String {
        get {
            return _gear
        }
        set {
            _gear = newValue
        }
    }
}
var vehicle = Vehicle()
vehicle.gear = "ADASD"
```

the reason it not crash when declared as `Int` in the first place is it's not running enough time to make it overflow, I tried it and it take me a while to got this error
[image]

Comment: thanks for the code, this made me realize that something is wrong with the code that i did

Comment: @Jeff I update the answer, there is no reason for `Int` not crash